# auto_arima results summary (intercept?)

Tags: python, time-series, arima

I ran auto_arima on my model from the library pmdarima and I'm trying to interpret the results printed to the console. I see two examples of similar parameters that yield different results:

ARIMA(0,1,0)(0,0,0)[108] **intercept** : OOB=.......

and

ARIMA(0,1,0)(0,0,0)[108]           : OOB=.......

The first example has the term "intercept" in the output but the second doesnt. The second instance has much better performance than the first, which indicates to me I want an ARIMA model with no intercept? I can't however find any indication in the ARIMA package that there's an "intercept" field I can either specify or not specify.

Any help is appreciated in understanding this output.

Thanks!